# extra Calligraphic phi

Tags: symbols

Looking for a command for this calligraphic phi

[image]

(`\varphi` is not the same and `\mathcal{\varphi}` does not work).

Solutions working under *mathjax* are more preferred.

Comment: This is an L, not a phi. Indeed `\mathscr{L}` also works with MathJax.

Comment: @egreg, thanks. I think reflected in the answer by bmv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be not a phi, but rather an L for me. On http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html, I found this solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{L}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This also works in MathJax: `$\mathscr{L}$`

(Tried here: https://www.mathjax.org/#demo)